# why does the progress bar not working when button insert is click in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I'm creating an insert button that will save records from list view to mysql database. When user clicked the insert button, the progress bar will show the progress until the records are inserted. The problem is, the progress bar only start after the insert task have been done.

This for vb.net, running mysql database. In the past, I've tried using countdown number and it also does not work.

```
'load form code
Private Sub formDevice_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Refresh()
        Timer2.Enabled = False
    End Sub

'insert button
Private Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
        Try
            Timer2.Enable = True
            Timer2.Start()

            Dim form As New editDevice
            form.lblName.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()

            For Each item As ListViewItem In lvLogs.Items


                Dim insert_command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO fingerprint(Enroll_no,Date_time,device_name)" & _
                                               "VALUES (@Enroll_no,@Date_time,@device_name)", connection)
                insert_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enroll_no", item.SubItems(1).Text)
                insert_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_time", item.SubItems(4).Text)
                insert_command.Parameters.Add("@device_name", MySqlDbType.UInt32).Value = form.lblName.Text

                connection.Open()

                If insert_command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then

                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Error")

                End If
                connection.Close()
            Next
            MessageBox.Show("Insert done")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try

'timer code
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
        If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
            Timer2.Stop()

        End If

    End Sub
```

I expect the progress bar will run when the insert button is clicked

Comment: Your `Click` event handler is executed on the UI thread, so that thread cannot do anything else until that method completes.  That means that, even though your `Timer` raises its `Tick` event, your event handler cannot be executed until all your data access is already complete.  The solution, as always, is to perform the work, i.e. the data access, in the background.  You could `Async`/`Await` or a `BackgroundWorker`.  There are other options but those would be the two main options.  No, I won't be telling you exactly how.  You need to research and make an attempt first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an [Application.DoEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents?view=netframework-4.8) call within your for loop

```
        For Each item As ListViewItem In lvLogs.Items


            Dim insert_command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO fingerprint(Enroll_no,Date_time,device_name)" & _
                                           "VALUES (@Enroll_no,@Date_time,@device_name)", connection)
            insert_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enroll_no", item.SubItems(1).Text)
            insert_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_time", item.SubItems(4).Text)
            insert_command.Parameters.Add("@device_name", MySqlDbType.UInt32).Value = form.lblName.Text

            connection.Open()

            If insert_command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Error")

            End If
            connection.Close()
            Application.DoEvents()
        Next
```

This lets your UI update (and other events be triggered) once in between each item processed.

Comment: Did your read and understand the Caution in the link you provided?

Comment: This is just an easy way to accomplish what they want without having to start a new thread or background worker. Those are more robust solutions but if you just want to update the UI while you are loading your application, it is probably ok.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the timer and progress bar for a while and just get your data entry code running smoothly.

Since you never show form, it is useless to fill a label on it. Just assign the value of the grid cell to the parameter.

Keep your data objects local so you can ensure that they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks will do this for you even if there is an error.

Do not create a new command and parameters in the loop. The only thing that changes on each iteration is the value of 2 of the parameters.

Do not use `.AddWithValue`  See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

I had to guess at the datatypes and sizes. Check you database for actual types and sizes.

Unless your connection to MySql is very slow or you have a huge number of items in your list view, you may not need a progress bar. If you do then refer to @jmcilhinney comment.

```
Private Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
    Try
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO fingerprint(Enroll_no,Date_time,device_name) VALUES (@Enroll_no,@Date_time,@device_name);", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Enroll_no", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date_time", MySqlDbType.DateTime)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@device_name", MySqlDbType.UInt32).Value = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
                cn.Open()
                Dim d As DateTime
                For Each item As ListViewItem In lvLogs.Items
                    DateTime.TryParse(item.SubItems(4).Text, d)
                    cmd.Parameters("@Enroll_no").Value = item.SubItems(1).Text
                    cmd.Parameters("@Date_time").Value = d
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("Insert done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```